# Build a Numpy array where datas match their own coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

I want to write a function with a tuple *s* (of length *n*) as an argument, which should return an array of shape ***s* concatenated with *(n,)*** (thus adding an extra dimension to the array), for which the data indexed by any tuple of length *n* (thus forgetting the last dimension) returns the tuple itself.

Here is an example of what it should do:

```
>>> a=f((2,3,4))
>>> a[1,1,1]
ndarray([1, 1, 1])
>>> a.shape
(2,3,4,3)
```

I managed to do it with the following code (if I am not wrong), but I am pretty sure it can be achieved in a more simple way:

```
a = np.transpose(
        np.meshgrid(
            *(np.arange(0, x) for x in s)),
        axes = (2,1) + tuple(range(3, n+1)) + (0,))
```

(I hope I correctly copied my code since I had to simplify variables here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`np.indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.indices.html) to generate those *ranged-indices*. To bring to the same format as the one proposed in the code listed in the question, we need to *push back* the first axis to the end.

So, we would have an implementation for `s` of generic length, like so -

```
s = (2,3,4)  # Input
out = np.indices(s).transpose(range(1,len(s)+1) + [0])
```

Alternatively, this pushing back of dimension could be achieved with [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) as well -

```
out = np.rollaxis(np.indices(s),0,len(s)+1)
```